# Establecer el tipo dinámicamente en un DataRow.Field<T>

Tags: c#, genericos, datarow

De antemano muchas gracias.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var miVariable = new MiClase();

        typeof(MiClase).GetProperties()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(prop => 
        {
            prop.SetValue(miVariable, x.Field<string>(prop.Name));
        });
```

Y lo que necesito hacer es que el tipo genérico de `x.Field<T>` lo obtenga de cada una de las propiedades de la clase.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `Field<T>` está pensado para cuando conoces el tipo `T` en tiempo de compilación, no es muy adecuado usarlo cuando sólo lo conoces en tiempo de ejecución. En este último caso usarlo requiere un poco de reflection de genéricos que no viene al caso puesto que `PropertyInfo.SetValue` espera el valor de la propiedad como un `object`. Así que en realidad es mucho más fácil de lo que esperas. Te funcionará cambiando el código de la siguiente manera:

```
var miVariable = new MiClase();

typeof(MiClase).GetProperties()
.ToList()
.ForEach(prop =>
{
    prop.SetValue(miVariable, x[prop.Name]);
});
```

Por otra parte sería bueno generalizar este código. Podrías tener un método extensor que te devolviera un objeto de una clase determinada a partir de un `DataRow`:

```
public static class CustomDataRowExtensions
{
    public static T As<T>(this DataRow row) where T : new()
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var result = new T();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            property.SetValue(result, row[property.Name]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

y lo podrías usar de la siguiente manera (suponiendo que x es un `DataRow`):

```
var miVariable = x.As<MiClase>();
```

Por supuesto, el método `As<T>` podría mejorarse. Una pega que tiene es que llama a GetProperties cada vez que llamas al método, lo cual tiene su coste en CPU y memoria. Pero eso es otra historia ...

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jesús-lópez me funcionó bastante, también seguí tu consejo y ahora ya no llamo a GetProperties dentro del método.